# Recursive Macroeconomics - Practice Questions

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for practice questions on recursive macroeconomics that focus on the following:

- Defining Competitive equilibriums (Arrow Debreu, Sequential Market, Recursive Competitive) for different situations and showing equivalence
- Solving Bellman equations and Lagrangians for various social planner problems
- Deriving Euler equations for the social planners problems.

I have been using Stokey and Lucas to study and would just like additional practice besides the exercises in Stokey and Lucas(1989).

Comment: Since you want recursive macroeconomics, I gotta recommend Recursive Macroeconomic Theory by Ljungqvist and Sargent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [UC Davis's Macro Prelims](https://economics.ucdavis.edu/graduate-program/current-students/past-preliminary-exams/prelims) to be most helpful in this regard. Ljungqvist and Sargent is also pretty decent.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at this:

[Exercises
in
Recursive Macroeconomic Theory
Stijn Van Nieuwerburgh
Pierre-Olivier Weill
Lars Ljungqvist
Thomas J. Sargent](https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Esvnieuwe/pdfs/masterex.pdf)